# ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_username_key" Detail: Key (username)=(test) already exists

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I have a problem trying to delete, then save a user in an application using the PostgreSQL database. Here is my controller:

```
@PostMapping
    public String addCalories(@RequestParam Integer consumedKcal, HttpServletRequest request){
        User u = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("u");
        User newUser = this.userService.save(u.getUsername(), u.getPassword(), u.getAge(), u.getGender(), u.getHeight(), u.getWeight(), u.getGoal(), u.getActivity_rate(), u.getKcal_needed(), u.getBmi(), consumedKcal);
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
```

Here is my service method:

```
@Override
@Transactional
    public User save(String username, String password, Integer age, String gender, Float height, Float weight, String goal, String activity_rate, Integer kcal_needed, Float bmi, Integer kcal_consumed) {
        this.userRepository.deleteUserByUsername(username);
        User u = new User(username, password, age, gender, height, weight, goal, activity_rate, kcal_needed, bmi, kcal_consumed);
        return this.userRepository.save(u);
    }
```

The repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    User findUserByUsername(String username);

    void deleteUserByUsername(String username);
}
```

The entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_app")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer username_id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Integer age;
    private String gender;
    private Float height;
    private Float weight;
    private String goal;
    private String activity_rate;
    private Integer kcal_needed;
    private Float bmi;
    private Integer kcal_consumed;
    private Integer water_consumed;
}
```

The JPA method delete works fine, it deletes the user. But I get this error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_username_key"   Detail: Key (username)=(test) already exists.` I don't know how to solve it. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Are you sure that delete works? As you've added "@Transactional" if something fails the whole operation is rolled back. And In your case I think your delete doesn't flush. So, when you try to save again the same value for unique column it failed.

Comment: @Sam the crux is that the underlying `EntityManager` may decide to reorder the recorded actions, i.e. execute the `INSERT` before the `DELETE`. An explicit `flush()` would resolve the issue.

Comment: Is the `userRepository` a `CrudRepository` or a `JpaRepository`? If it is a `JpaRepository`, then a call to `userRepository.flush();` after `userRepository.deleteByUsername(...);` should resolve the issue.

Comment: What is the code for your User class entity? Which GeneratorType are you using? Is join @Sam and ask: Are you sure calling the "delete" method was successful? Try to getByFirstName(String) - is it declared in your Repository class? see if you get anything from calling it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've added flush() after delete() and it works!

Comment: @Programmer2B We can do a flush. But beware. Doing flush() will degrade performance as you've added in a single transaction. Instead try to update the managed entity rather than deleting it.

Comment: I second @Sam's comment. We should try to merge the new entity with the existing one for better performance.

Comment: You need to be familiar with what are you using and code accordingly, calling "flush()" is not always the best practice - you should be aware of what might happen. What are you using, Hibernate Session or JPA EntityManager? When asking this kind of question, please, attach all your code for Entity, Repository, and service classes. Mainly the Id, Column, and Table annotations in the entity class. The correct way to do "delete" is to get the entitt(ies) you want to delete and then delete what you found.

Comment: I've updated the code, I hope it is more clear now. I appreciate your help!